# flutter Navigate to other screen via Routing updates every other screen

Tags: navigation, flutter

I have been trying to find out what causes the behaviour described below:

1. I have a flutter app with many screens
2. Navigation to the various screens is implemented using Routes and a Drawer that Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/XX") to them.

Here is the Routing like:

```
Routes() {
   runApp( new StateContainer(child:
      new MaterialApp(
      title: "My App",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
        ? Colors.blueGrey[900] : Colors.blueGrey[900],
        accentColor: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
        ? Colors.grey[900] : Colors.grey[900],
        ),
      home: new LoginScreen(),

      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> { //5
        '/login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginScreen(), //LoginScreen
        '/signup' : (BuildContext context) => new SignupScreen(), // SignupScreen
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomeScreen(), //HomeScreen


      },

    )));
  }

}
```

The problem is; every time I navigate to a screen, all the other screen updates in the background. I know because I set console print("I am here"); in each screen.

Is this the normal behaviour? I do want this because it is wasting CPU resources.

I hope I have some clues on what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the normal behaviour?

Yes, routes are by default added on top of previous routes,
and you should in general expect the `built()` method to be called at any time.

> I do want this because it is wasting CPU resources.

Not really. The build method shouldn't do to much work anyway except of creating widget instances and the expensive work is layouting and rendering to the GPU, which won't be done if the view hasn't changed.

Comment: I am fetching data in the one of the other screen and I notice that everytime I navigate to other screen, the data fetching is executing....

Comment: If you hold the data in a variable you can easily check if the data was already fetched and skip the fetching in case it's already available.